# Return JSP in AJAX response?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have an Action class which has method which calls a Bean and sets some data in the DB based on some inputs.

**Action class**:

```
try{
    slsConfigureTspThresholdRemote = this.getSlsConfigureTspThresholdRemote();
    slsConfigureTspThresholdRemote.setThresholdParameters(circleId, tspId, thresholdTypeFlag, thresholdParametersList);
}
catch (Exception e){    
    addActionError(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("[AnalysisStatisticsAction] updateThresholdParameters: In catch Inside Constructor!!");
    return ERROR;
}
return DISPLAY;
```

If there is an `ERROR` i return an `Error.jsp` where `actionError` are displayed and if `DISPLAY` then the same input page is returned.

**strust.xml**:

```
<action name="updateThresholdParameters"
            class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction" method="updateThresholdParameters">

            <result name="display">pages/ConfigureTspThresholdInput.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">pages/Error.jsp</result>

        </action>
```

I use strust2-json-plugin. I am doing an AJAX call.

**JS**:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,                  
                url: '/gma/updateThresholdParameters.action',
                data:
                {
                    circleId: circleId,
                    tspId: tspId,
                    thresholdTypeFlag: thresholdTypeFlag,
                    thresholdParameters: thresholdParameters
                },
                success: function(data){
                     alert('Updated DB');
                },
                error:function(data){
                    alert("something is not fine!!!");
                }
         });
```

So if data is updated in DB i `alert('Updated DB')` or if exception then I want my `Error.jsp` to be loaded in `ErrorDiv`.

So the problem is:

If no exception occurs in my `data` then `ConfigureTspThresholdInput.jsp` is returned and if exception is there then `Error.jsp` is returned in data. How should I differentiate which jsp is there in data so that accordingly I `alert('Updated DB')` or load `Error.jsp` in `errorDiv`??

I tried searching online. I read about `statusCode` and `ErrorCode` of JSON plugin, but with that I don't know how data part is filled(I alert and got an XML doc).

**EDIT**: From the answers I guess people are misunderstanding the question. So let me clear.

When I say exception I am not saying that AJAX request *itself* could not be done or it failed.

I mean if there was an Exception in bean I return `error` and accordingly in my `strust.xml` i return `Error.jsp`.
So I know that control will come to `success` of AJAX request. After reaching there how to handle the 2 JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to trace exception in ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,                  
                url: '/gma/updateThresholdParameters.action',
                data:
                {
                    circleId: circleId,
                    tspId: tspId,
                    thresholdTypeFlag: thresholdTypeFlag,
                    thresholdParameters: thresholdParameters
                },
                success: function(data){
                     alert('Updated DB');
                },
                error:function(data){
                    alert("something is not fine!!!");
                }
         });
```

Comment: Please Edits to my question

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% sure I understand your question. What I get from it is:

You want your site to alert "Updated DB" if there was no error and everything went smooth;
else you want your site to show an error page?

You should use HTTP Status codes to report wether the request went good or bad. Use a status code of 5XX for a server error. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

When your ajax request receives an error status code it will call the error function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,                  
        url: '/gma/updateThresholdParameters.action',
        data:
        {
            circleId: circleId,
            tspId: tspId,
            thresholdTypeFlag: thresholdTypeFlag,
            thresholdParameters: thresholdParameters
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("DB updated")
        },
        error: function () {
            Redirect to your error page instead of returning it.
        }
    });
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Please Edits to my question

Answer (score 0):

You should use Shorthands to keep code clean.

```
$('#OkDiv').load('/gma/updateThresholdParameters.action',{
  circleId: circleId,
  tspId: tspId,
  thresholdTypeFlag: thresholdTypeFlag,
  thresholdParameters: thresholdParameters
},function(a,c,xhr){if(c=='error')$('#ErrorDiv').html(xhr.responseHTML);});
```

1. Its automatically POST
2. Its automatically traditional
3. Its automatically replaced

Comment: If  there is error, Then it's ok. However, If it's a success then this will load my result-page to my ErrorDiv, which I don't want

Comment: You are right, try it now. In global scope you better use `http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/`